# Twitter Bootstrap Navbar Issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, overlapping

Let me first of say that I have researched this and that none of the answers have helped me.  I have to be doing something wrong, I just don't know what.  As you can see, I have tried the body CSS which I have also found here, but that still didn't work.  I looked up a site and used their code which got my content directly under the navbar opposed to under it, but I still want some space between the 2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>siteName || Welcome!</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<!-- JavaScript plugins (requires jQuery) -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Optionally enable responsive features in IE8 -->
<script src="js/respond.js"></script>

body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
}
@media(max-width: 980px) {
/* Enable use of floated navbar text */
.navbar-text.pull-right {
      float: none;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="brand" href="#">siteName</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Links<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">site1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">site2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">site3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse navbar-btn pull-right">Sign in</button>
        <form class="navbar-search pull-right"><input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search"></form>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9 well">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <p>Welcome, this isn't lowering down at all :c</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add a <style> before your css code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot your style code.

I just took a quick sample out of the section to add the code:

```
    <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
```

Right here there should be a

```
    <style>
```

tag that will mean that this is start of some styling.

```
    body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 80px;
```

Then, of course, I see that you already have the end tag of style here:

```
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    }
    }
    </style>
```

Hope these tips help!

Comment: Looks like it's been a year already... Apologies if I'm trying to bring back a dead thread.